# Group files and directories based on first letter of their name and move them to directories of that letter

Tags: bash, wildcards, mv

I have a directory with the following content:

```bsh
$ mkdir dir && cd "$_"
~/dir $ mkdir a1 a2 a3 a4 b1 c1 c2 1a 2a 2b 2c 2d 3a _1 _2
~/dir $ touch a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 b_1 c_1 c_2 1_a 2_a 2_b 2_c 2_d 3_a __1 __2
~/dir $ ls
__1  1_a  __2  2_a  2_b  2_c  2_d  3_a  a_1  a_2  a_3  a_4  b_1  c_1  c_2
_1   1a   _2   2a   2b   2c   2d   3a   a1   a2   a3   a4   b1   c1   c2
```

Now I want to group all these files and directories *based on their first letter* and move them to *directories of the same letter*. So the output would be:

```bsh
~/dir $ ls
_  1  2  3  a  b  c
```

And using [exa](https://github.com/ogham/exa), the tree would look something like this:

```bsh
~/dir $ exa --tree
.
├── 1
│  ├── 1_a
│  └── 1a
├── 2
│  ├── 2_a
│  ├── 2_b
│  ├── 2_c
│  ├── 2_d
│  ├── 2a
│  ├── 2b
│  ├── 2c
│  └── 2d
├── 3
│  ├── 3_a
│  └── 3a
├── _
│  ├── _1
│  ├── _2
│  ├── __1
│  └── __2
├── a
│  ├── a1
│  ├── a2
│  ├── a3
│  ├── a4
│  ├── a_1
│  ├── a_2
│  ├── a_3
│  └── a_4
├── b
│  ├── b1
│  └── b_1
└── c
   ├── c1
   ├── c2
   ├── c_1
   └── c_2
```

I know I can move using wildcards:

```bsh
~/dir $ mkdir a && mv a* a
```

Which throws an error:

```bsh
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘a’: File exists
```

But it gets the job done. And I can do something like this to avoid the error:

```bsh
~/dir $ mkdir temp && mv a* temp && mv temp a
```

And then I could use that in a for loop for every letter that I know. But the problem is that I don't know what those first letters could possibly be, we have quite a lot of letters. Is there a way I can achieve this without the need to know those letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate over all the things:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *; do 
    firstChar="${f:0:1}"; 
    mkdir -p -- "$firstChar"; 
    mv -- "$f" "$firstChar"; 
done
```

The `-p` tells `mkdir` not to complain if the directory already exists  and `${f:0:1}` is Ksh/Bash/Zsh syntax for "get the first character".

And here it is in action:

```
$ mkdir a1 a2 a3 a4 b1 c1 c2 1a 2a 2b 2c 2d 3a _1 _2
$ touch a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 b_1 c_1 c_2 1_a 2_a 2_b 2_c 2_d 3_a __1 __2
$ ls -F
__1  _1/  1_a  1a/  __2  _2/  2_a  2a/  2_b  2b/  2_c  2c/  2_d  2d/  3_a  3a/  a_1  a1/  a_2  a2/  a_3  a3/  a_4  a4/  b_1  b1/  c_1  c1/  c_2  c2/

$ for f in *; do 
    firstChar="${f:0:1}"; 
    mkdir -p "$firstChar"; 
    mv -- "$f" "$firstChar"; 
done

$ tree
.
├── _
│   ├── __1
│   ├── _1
│   ├── __2
│   └── _2
├── 1
│   ├── 1_a
│   └── 1a
├── 2
│   ├── 2_a
│   ├── 2a
│   ├── 2_b
│   ├── 2b
│   ├── 2_c
│   ├── 2c
│   ├── 2_d
│   └── 2d
├── 3
│   ├── 3_a
│   └── 3a
├── a
│   ├── a_1
│   ├── a1
│   ├── a_2
│   ├── a2
│   ├── a_3
│   ├── a3
│   ├── a_4
│   └── a4
├── b
│   ├── b_1
│   └── b1
└── c
    ├── c_1
    ├── c1
    ├── c_2
    └── c2

22 directories, 15 files
```

Note that if you can have existing file or directory names that are only one character, that will cause errors. For instance, if you create a file called `a` and try the above approach, you will get:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘a’: File exists
mv: 'a' and 'a' are the same file
```

If that is a problem, you could do something convoluted like renaming to a temp file, creating the directory, and moving the file into it:

```
for f in *; do 
    firstChar="${f:0:1}";
    ## if the first character exists as a dir, move the file there
    if [[ -d "$firstChar" ]]; then
       mv -- "$f" "$firstChar"; 
    ## if it exists but is not a dir, move to a temp location,
    ## re-create it as a dir, and move back from temp
    elif [[ -e "$firstChar" ]]; then
        tmp=$(mktemp ./tmp.XXXXX)
        mv -- "$firstChar" "$tmp"
        mkdir -p "$firstChar"
        mv -- "$tmp" "$firstChar"/"$f"
    else    
        mkdir -p "$firstChar"; 
        mv -- "$f" "$firstChar"; 
    fi
done
```

Comment: In my case there are regular files `f`, `fu` and `fuu`. Will I lose data?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski good point. You won't lose data, but the `f` would cause errors. See update.

Comment: I have tested the basic code of yours. I lost data because all the files overwrote `f` one by one. Improvement: `mv -- "$f" "$firstChar"/`.

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly:

```
find . -path './*' -prune -exec sh -c '
    j="${1%${1#???}}"; mkdir "$j" && mv -- "$1" "$j/"
' _ {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that hasn't been mentioned is to find all the unique first letters of files and directories, move everything to a temporary directory, create the first letter directory, and then move back everything.

```bsh
letters=($(ls -1 | sort -n | cut -c 1 | uniq))
temp=$(mktemp -dp .)
for letter in "${letters[@]}"; do
    mv "$letter"* "$temp";
    mkdir "$letter";
    mv "$temp/"* "$letter";
done
rm -r "$temp"
```

With this approach, *one-letter directories and files* are also taken care of. In action:

```bsh
$ mkdir a1 a2 a3 a4 b1 c1 c2 1a 2a 2b 2c 2d 3a _1 _2
$ touch a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 b_1 c_1 c_2 1_a 2_a 2_b 2_c 2_d 3_a __1 __2
$ mkdir a b c
$ touch 1 2 3 _
$ ls -F
_    1    __2  2_a  2b/  2_d  3_a  a_1  a2/  a_4  b_1  c_1  c2/
__1  1_a  _2/  2a/  2_c  2d/  3a/  a1/  a_3  a4/  b1/  c1/
_1/  1a/  2    2_b  2c/  3    a/   a_2  a3/  b/   c/   c_2
```

And after that script, the result becomes:

```bsh
$ ls -F
_/  1/  2/  3/  a/  b/  c/
$ exa --tree
.
├── 1
│  ├── 1
│  ├── 1_a
│  └── 1a
├── 2
│  ├── 2
│  ├── 2_a
│  ├── 2_b
│  ├── 2_c
│  ├── 2_d
│  ├── 2a
│  ├── 2b
│  ├── 2c
│  └── 2d
├── 3
│  ├── 3
│  ├── 3_a
│  └── 3a
├── _
│  ├── _
│  ├── _1
│  ├── _2
│  ├── __1
│  └── __2
├── a
│  ├── a
│  ├── a1
│  ├── a2
│  ├── a3
│  ├── a4
│  ├── a_1
│  ├── a_2
│  ├── a_3
│  └── a_4
├── b
│  ├── b
│  ├── b1
│  └── b_1
└── c
   ├── c
   ├── c1
   ├── c2
   ├── c_1
   └── c_2
```

With this approach, you create only the necessary directories. So the `mkdir` commands runs the least amount of times possible.

Edit: As [@terdon mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645407/group-files-and-directories-based-on-first-letter-of-their-name-and-move-them-to/645527#comment1209623_645412), parsing the output of `ls` will cause the command to fail on files with `newline` in their names. To fix that, we can use this:

```bsh
temp=$(mktemp -dp .)
for f in *; do
    letter="${f:0:1}";
    mv -- "$letter"* "$temp";
    mkdir "$letter";
    mv "$temp/"* "$letter";
done
rm -r "$temp"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the solution for your move pattern is simple, just add a `?`. That only matches `a` followed by at least another character.

```
mv a?* a
```

We don't have that many letters, but to find all actually present letters, you can use this command. `sed` removes everything after the first letter, sort uniq removes the duplicates.

```
ls | sed -r 's/^(.).*$/\1/' | sort -u
```

Comment: Note that your sed approach will fail if any file names contain newlines.

Comment: @terdon Yes. But have you ever seen newline in file names in real life?

Comment: Yes, of course. Many times. Usually because of a bug somewhere, but not always. More importantly, such files can be trivially created (e.g. `touch foo$'\n'bar`) so we should make sure we can deal with them.

Comment: @RalfFriedl, of nothing else, we see them every time we test the answers we write here on the site :D

Comment: @RalfFriedl, but, a world where such effed-up filenames were not possible would indeed be a nicer one. We just need to convince every Unix-like system to add some limitations. Or at least convince them to read https://dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
() { mkdir ${(uM)@#?}; } ??* && zmv '(?)?*' '$1/$f'
```

We have:

- `() { body; } args`: an anonymous function, here passed the expansion of `??*` (the file names made of at least 2 characters) as arguments. In the body:
- `${@#?}` would be the args stripped of their first character, but with the `M` (for matched) parameter expansion flag, that's reversed and only the first character is retained instead. `u` (for unique) removes duplicates.
- then `zmv '(?)?*' '$1/$f'` moves the files with at least 2 characters into their respective folder.